# Which event column (Calendar Provider) corresponds to event id (Google Calendar API)?

Tags: android, google-api, google-calendar-api

I would like to retrieve a Google Calendar event using [get](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/get) from Google Calendar API:

```
String myEventID = ... // ?
Event event = service.events().get("primary", myEventID).execute();
```

Is it possible to get this myEventID parameter using Calendar Provider? [Events table](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.EventsColumns.html) does not seem to contain anything similar to event id (CalendarContract.Events._ID is a totally different thing).

Comment: check this link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.Events.html . If you do events.list, https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list you will get the event id's list in your calendar. TO get more details about particular event, given event id in events.get https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/get

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it does not help. That ID obtained by events().list() is an alphanumeric token like "abcdef123...". The event ID obtained by Calendar Provider is a number like 89 - it is just a primary key in the table. What I need is any ID/UUID which can be obtained (and it will be the same) using both Calendar Provider and Google Calendar API (events.list/get).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CalendarContract.Events._SYNC_ID is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

`CalendarContract.Events._ID` is unique ID for a row.